# Can an Employer use a photo of you taken at work without your permission?

Tags: employees, australia

The company I work for is small and only has about 12 employees including me and my employer, the company also has a website and on one page it descries the team's roles by having a photo of the team member and their role, ie,

```
        [image]
      John Smith
Graphic Design/Marketing
```

the purpose of this is to have another blank team member being

```
   [default image]
        You?
Link to Careers Page
```

now when me and another guy was employed a few months ago we had the default image when we was listed on this page with all the other team members with some random photo of themselves. now my employer must have wanted that when our photos gets updated everyone else's would be updated to be more professional. the thing was that I did not want my photo on the website, call it more of a paranoia of having my photo on the net and misused than being camera shy. I told my employer that I did not want my photo taken and scheduled my lunch break to be when the photos were being taken so I wasn't in everyone's way.

now I just recently checked the website and it has been updated with the photos, however with me it seems that my employer has taken a photo of me while I was focused on the pc with my headphones on and considering how often I work like this I don't know when it was taken.

now aside from how my photo looks out of place with everyone elses where they are smiling, their facing off at an angle from their body with a grey background while mine is me staring at a computer with a brick wall in the background I also told my employer that I didn't want my photo taken (when he asked why I told him it was just a paranoia about it being misused) and he said it was ok.

I check my employment contract and while it talks about how the employer can amend the duties and tasks an employee will undertake after consultation with the employee but I was told that my refusal to have my photo taken was fine, but ofcause in a way I never did refuse to allow any photo of my to not be posted however it was my assumption that there was none.

I would complain however since I am still in my initial probation period before I secure the full time position, I am being payed as a casual employee with only the added pay loading because I don't get sick or annual leave and with that they can just fire me without notice and I have not seen any similar roles available elsewhere for the past couple of months and i'm kinda worried that if I demand my photo to be taken down from the website my employer can twist that as my wanting to quit and given what he has done I wouldn't put it pass him to do that and I can afford to loose my job yet.

So I am wondering, can an employer take your photo, taken during work hours and use it for the company without your permission?

<sup>I know it kinda sounds stupid that I wasn't aware that my photo was taken as I worked but when I am focused like this with my music playing I can block out the entire world and often I forget that there are other people around me and get a huge shock when someone taps be to get my attention</sup>

Comment: It's not stupid that you didn't notice a photo being taken. It means you were in the zone hard a work - something your employer should value!

Comment: Legal question. Specify a location or (preferably) find a lawyer.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, since I am not a lawyer and I have no idea in what jurisdiction you live in, but may be as an alternative solution, you could submit your own photo. That photo could be a photo of you when you were a toddler for instance, or a photo of you modified to look like a cartoon, or a photo of your cat, or something else entirely, or whatever else would fit your company culture, and your personal taste. I have no idea what those are either.

Comment: If you look at [Stack Exchange's team page](http://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Community), you will see there are quite a lot of people who don't like their faces visible. That's normal, and any company should be able to deal with it. Of course at SE it's very employee-friendly. A strictly shirt-and-tie shop might not want you to wear a microwave on your head for the picture, but there should be ways.

Comment: "I also told my employer that I didn't want my photo taken...and he said it was ok" - Before you consider legal issues, contact this boss and ask about it. It could be a simple communications issue (e.g. someone else put the photo up without knowing you didn't approve).

Comment: A few year ago and not the same but Tiger Woods sued the PGA for over using his likeness and I think he won.  But one picture is not over using your likeness.   I think it is disrespectful they posted your picture without your permission but I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is unreasonable for you to ask about it. That's different than demanding. Explaining that it makes you uncomfortable is fair game. Are you comfortable with your name being used. If so, maybe they can write something like "also Carmira C; not pictured" and take your photo down.